# When making an AJAX POST request with Yii, how is $_GET['ajax'] automatically set?

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview

I'm using the Yii framework to develop a basic CRUD app. I noticed that the auto-generated code in the action functions often contains the following lines:

```
// if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
     $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
```

The part I can't figure out is that this code works even when I'm doing an AJAX POST, and even when the 'ajax' parameter does not appear in the request when I examine it with Firebug or Fiddler. Does the server make another GET request to itself, or is there something about `$_GET` that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Can you give us a link, where this happens in your opinion?

Comment: can you show how you are doing the ajax post?

Comment: Now I can see the 'ajax' parameter in the POST. But should that be available using the $_GET array?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19324-whats-isset-getajax-for-in-the-generated-code/

Looks like it's set by Yii if you're doing an Ajax call using Yii libraries

Comment: Yes, it is, and I can see it now in the request. The part I'm confused about is why they use `$_GET` to check for a posted parameter. Does that work for both GET and POST?

Comment: Think it's used for GET requests (when handling pagination / grid reloads and also for the delete handling. To simplify their code, I don't think they differentiate ...

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. Does $_GET still work even if it's posted? Because delete is only allowed via POST, and that line definitely appears in the delete action.